# Cant connect to Cloud SQL from Cloud Composer using Public IP

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to connect my instance of Google Composer to Google cloud Postgres. I am trying to do this via the Public IP.
The DAG error is saying I cant connect to the server. The DAG is using a postgres operator.

[image]

I then have a connection configured in my composer instance. This has the public ip of my Cloud SQL Postgres server.

[image]

I think the error is around not allowing the cloud composer ip into the firewall for the Cloud SQL server. Am I doing this the wrong way? Should I be using a different operator? Ive been stuck on this for a few days now and exhausted my options from google.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have to update the [authorized network](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/authorize-networks) on Cloud SQL to allow the Composer public IP. Be sure to only grant the public IP.

In addition, keep in mind that, out of the box, the Cloud SQL traffic is not encrypted and if you use private IP with CLoud SQL proxy, it's strongly recommended to [add SSL on the Cloud SQL database](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-ssl-instance)

Comment: Really appreciate the comment, i thought this would be the issue but I couldn't find the Composer public ip. Are you able to point me in the right direction? 
I know I should use Cloud proxy but this is just a proof of concept project.

Comment: I know how to do it only when you use a private Composer (1 or 2). You have to plug a Cloud NAT and reserve your public IP. Else, I don't know, I guess it's a Google Cloud shared IP, and you can't trust it. https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/private-ip-environments#public_internet_access_for_your_workflows

Comment: So does that mean the only way to do it is using a Proxy? Because composer is a service I cant reserve a public ip can I? I guess if they are both in the same VPC they should be able to talk to eachother? Still very confused lol

Comment: Yes, by default you are in a managed world and you haven't the capacity to customize it. You have to use the private mode for that. And Yes Cloud SQL and Composer Private can talk each other with private IP. Why? Because they aren't in the same VPC (really!). Cloud SQL is in a Google managed VPC peered with your VPC. Composer is also in a Google managed VPC peered with your VPC. And because the VPC peering is not transitif, you can't can't reach Cloud SQL VPC  from Composer VPC through your project VPC (yes, it's a brain twister!)

Comment: Appreciate the effort, I think I will try follow some guides of using a proxy to connect them. Thank you so much